# C program that adds data into a file then sorts the data entered

Tags: c

This is what I've got so far....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

FILE *fp;

int n,num;
int i,j;
int result,index;
char name[50][50];        
char jar[1024];
char temp[1000];

main()
{     
    clrscr();

    fp=fopen("EXO-KAI.docx","a+");

    printf("\nHow Many Names You Want to Add: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("\nEnter Name:\n");
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&name[i]);
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n",name[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        index=i;                 
        for(j=i+1;j<num;j++)
        {
            result=strcmp(name[index],name[j]);
            if(result>0)                               
                index=j;
        }
        strcpy(temp,name[index]);
        strcpy(name[index],name[i]);
        strcpy(name[i],temp);
    }

    fp=fopen("EXO-LAY.docx","a+");

    printf("\nThe Sorted Names are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",name[i]);
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n", name[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    getch();

}
```

In the first run, the sorted names are written into the file. In the second run, the program should read the written names in the file and sort it together with the new names. But this doesn't work. Can you please help me?

Comment: If the file you're reading and writing to is a MS Word document, which the extension `docx`would suggest, this won't work as that file type has a very specific format and cannot be treated like a normal text file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are using bubble sort to sort all strings, but you put the string swap outside the inner loop. So this doesn't change the string order correctly when the string `name[j]` is greater than the string `name[index]`. So in order to do the sort on the string, you can do:

```
for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
    for(j=i+1;j<num;j++) {
        index = i;
        result=strcmp(name[index],name[j]);
        if(result>0) {
            strcpy(temp,name[index]);
            strcpy(name[index],name[j]);
            strcpy(name[j],temp);
            index = j;
        }
    }
}
```

So if the string `name[j]` is greater than `name[index]`, the do the swap. Otherwise do nothing.

The bubble sort method you use has a complexity of `O(N^2)`. So a better approach is using quick sort which on average has `O(NlogN)` complexity. To do this, you can use C's library function `qsort()` to achieve this. First you can define your own string comparator:

```
int my_str_compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp((char*) a, (char*) b);
}
```

Then you can invoke `qsort` function directly to replace the for loop in your code:

```
qsort (&name[0], num, 50, my_str_compare);
```

This will does the same sorting as yours but in general faster.